# Apriori in C# - Error: Index was out of range

Tags: c#, indexoutofboundsexception

My soluton here: http://www.mediafire.com/?rzrhvc71musz793

I get error "Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection" in line 238 file Apriori.cs

```
private List<Rule> GenerateRules()
{
    var rules = new List<Rule>();

    foreach (var item in _allFrequentItems)
    {
        if (item.val.Count > 1)
        {
            int maxCombinationLength = item.val.Count / 2;
            GenerateCombination(item.val, maxCombinationLength, ref rules);
        }
    }

    return rules;
}
private void GenerateCombination(List<int> item, int combinationLength, ref List<Rule> rules)
{
    int itemLength = item.Count;

    switch (itemLength)
    {
        case 2:
            AddItem(new List<int>(){item[0]}, item, ref rules);
            break;
        case 3:
            for (int i = 0; i < itemLength; i++)
            {
                AddItem(new List<int>{item[i]}, item, ref rules);
            }
            break;
        default:
            for (int i = 0; i < itemLength; i++)
            {
                GetCombinationRecursive(new List<int>() { item[i] }, item, combinationLength, ref rules);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

In GenerateRules() i have check item.val.Count>1 and in GenerateCombination itemLength = item.Count..Why in my debug item.Count =1 , itemLength =3????

Comment: AddItem(new List<int>{item[i]}, item, ref rules); in case 3: is line 238

Comment: I would guess that `AddItem` (that you've not shown us) manipulates its second argument (`item`) and removes items from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List is reference type. 
So when you modify your `item` in `GetRemaining` method, you remove element from your original list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemLength; i++)
{
    AddItem(new List<int>{item[i]}, item, ref rules);
}
```

`i = 0`, you remove one element from item. `item.Count = 2`;

`i = 1`, you remove ome more element. `item.Count = 1`;

`i = 2`; you try to access `item[2]`, but there is only one element in it

Comment: tks you :D, i change GetRemaining method set _parent = new List<int>(parent)